# Method to "Intervene" after a login, to force user to update contact info

Tags: onelogin

Every 3 months, we have a requirement to force a user to an app to update their contact info (this is an in-house app, and we also will have situation that is an app to update emergency alert phone and email addresses) before they can access any other apps on the onelogin dashboard. Once a user has updated their info, then they can access the onelogin dashboard as usual. Do you have any examples or provide any ideas of how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

An account administrator can log into their companies onelogin portal.
In the upper right hand corner there is link `Administration` click it.
In the administration panel hover over the `Security` tab and select `Policies` when it appears.

Start a new policy. On the left side there is a tab `Password`. This allows you to enforce the password age policy.

Once the policy has been configured, it just needs to be applied to the users.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but sorry that my question was not clear about what I was asking. I have made an edit. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah this should work for you. Create a user policy that requires a password change every 90 days. Apply that policies to all users and your problem is solved.

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for answering! I am still puzzled about this idea, although maybe it gives me a glimmer of hope. We don't want a user to change their password every 90 days. We just want them to go to an app which is a form to key in some information. Are you saying its possible to implement this policy and for a password change to not occur?

Comment: Oh, I see there is an external application, I missed that part. I am on the engineering side of the company and I am not an expert on all the features, but depending on your app, you require MFA to log into onelogin. If your app can support a push notification for MFA, you can do the required checks there and your clients will only be able to log into the portal once the MFA is completed